# Non https main site redirects to https with directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this piece of code to redirect all http to https in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Works great. But my only problem is if I access the root non http

```
http://example.com redirects to https://www.example.com/dev/
```

/dev is the directory where the main site is located.

my cpanel directory is like this

```
public_html/dev <---- https://www.example.com
```

How can I fix this issue. It should redirect to https version without the dev directory.
Hope someone could shed a light on this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
To make it more clear here's the directory structure
[image]

The contents of .htaccess in public_html is

*public_html/.htaccess*

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !dev/
rewriterule (.*) /dev/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldurl\.com$ [OR] // if old url redirect to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldurl\.com$ // if old url redirect to example.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

here's the contents of .htaccess file in public_html/dev

*public_html/dev/.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So, `example.com` is actually an addon domain? Not the primary domain? And the document root of the addon domain points to a subdirectory off the main domain? And the `.htaccess` file is located in the _parent_ directory (above the document root)?

Comment: @MrWhite, example.com is the primary domain. Its files are located in public_html/dev. I have 2 htaccess files. one in the root public_html/.htaccess and one in the dev which is the one i posted. Would you like me to post the .htaccess on the root? thanks

Comment: Yes, if you could post the `.htaccess` file from the parent directory as well that would be great. So, to clarify, the document-root is actually `public_html` but you are presumably internally rewriting the request to the `/dev` subdirectory? Although, "my cpanel directory is like this" would appear to suggest that `public_html/dev` is actually the document-root?

Comment: @MrWhite, Sure I'll add it. I'll update my post. yes document root is public_html. While public_html/dev is where site files are located.

Comment: @MrWhite, I've updated my post. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way.

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www\.example\.com [R=301,L]

# enforce HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# First add a trailing slash if dev/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dev/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# forward everything to /dev directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* dev/$0 [L]
```

**public_html/dev/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely before testing this changge.